# Contact form error on submit

Tags: php, forms

I've built a basic contact form using the following:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From:  Contact'; 
    $to = 'info@mydomain.com'; 
    $subject = 'message';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Contact Number: $contact\n Message:\n $message";
?>

<form id="contact-1" method="post">

    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" placeholder="YOUR NAME">

    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS">

    <label>Contact Number</label>
    <input name="contact" type="tel" placeholder="TELEPHONE">

    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
<?php
if ($_POST['submit'] ) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been submitted</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, please try again!</p>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

If you leave the `name` input blank and submit the form, its successful. However, if I add anything the name input. the form doesnt send and the site loads a 'page not found'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add type="text" into first input element.

Comment: And why does OP has to add this? What does it do?

Comment: It shouldn't do anything. `type="text"` is the default.

Answer (score 0):

This code appeared to have worked for me, test it out and see if the mail sends properly.

I added the

```
type="text"
```

to Name, and added

```
isset()
```

around

```
$_POST['submit']
```

I enclosed the top potion with

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
```

To avoid errors before the page is first submitted.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From:  Contact'; 
    $to = 'info@mydomain.com'; 
    $subject = 'message';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Contact Number: $contact\n Message:\n $message";
}
?>

<form id="contact-1" method="post">

    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="YOUR NAME">

    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS">

    <label>Contact Number</label>
    <input name="contact" type="tel" placeholder="TELEPHONE">

    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been submitted</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, please try again!</p>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response!

Comment: You only want to send the email and/or the success/fail message only after the form is submitted

What the isset here is doing is testing if the form has been submitted (the name of your submit button (from the HTML) is "submit" so that is why we're testing $_POST['submit'] )